# Which web browsers support Gelocation via HTML5?

Tags: html, geolocation

Which web browsers (and version) support Gelocation via HTML5?

Comment: what do you mean by Geolocation via HTML5? Geolocation is implemented using API and HTML5 is markup language

Comment: @coder, http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/basics.html#DetectingUserLocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the desktop only firefox (not sure if opera already includes it in official builds), on mobile: mobile safari 3 & android 2.x browser

more info about support on:

- the desktop: http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus
- mobile: http://www.quirksmode.org/webkit.html#t013

hope this helps,
frank

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean geolocation API's,

Firefox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_geolocation

Safari:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/GettingGeographicalLocations/GettingGeographicalLocations.html

Opera:
http://my.opera.com/core/blog/geolocation-enabled-build

And more about it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API

Answer (score 0):

Geolocation on Safari is iPhone only

Google Chrome beta has optional support: http://www.wait-till-i.com/2010/03/04/google-chrome-getting-navigator-geolocation/

Unfortunately Opera 10.50 does not seem to have geolocation, which is a bit of bummer considering how great it looks in most other regards. (Video, audio, CSS3 improvements + Carakan really smokes V8, Squirrelfish and Tracemonkey.)